# Programmatic HazelcastInstance for WebFilter

Tags: hazelcast

We recently jumped versions from Hazelcast 3.2 to 3.7. In 3.2, we could create a HazelcastInstance for the WebFilter by overriding getInstance(Properties) rather than use the (default) XML builder. 
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/web/WebFilter.html

This allowed us to use the programmatic API to configure the WebFilter in our own way rather than having to manually edit hazelcast XML files or use multicast.

In 3.7, this looks to have been removed and there doesn't seem to a different straight forward approach for using the programmatic API with WebFilter.

Is there a different way to use the programmatic API to create the HazelcastInstance for WebFilter that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ?

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("instance-name", hazelcastInstance.getName());

WebFilter webFilter = new WebFilter(properties);
```

Create the Hazelcast instance from XML or programmatically, and pass into the constructor for the WebFilter via the properties.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The Properties passed in to the constructor (or web.xml) only dictate things like instance-name and where to find the config XML. You can't do things like turn off multi-cast or add network interfaces. Our current workaround is to specify instance name and have another servlet configure the HazelcastInstance with the same instance name we give WebFilter. There is a 10sec delay in attempting to configure the Hazelcast Instance so this is working, but there is still a timing issue we're nervous about.